# Find an x amount of subarrays such that the total sum of those subarrays is minimum

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, dynamic-programming

Find an x amount of non-overlapping and continuous subarrays such that the total sum of those subarray's is minimum, and the count of all elements are y.

```
Example 1:
Input: {2,1, 10, 40, 5, 6} , x=2, y=4
Output: {{2,1},{5,6}}
```

---

```
Example 2:
Input: {2,1, 10, 40, 5, 6} , x=1, y=2
Output: {{2,1}}
```

---

```
Example 3:
Input: {2,1, 10, 40, 5, 6} , x=1, y=3
Output: {{2,1,10}}
```

---

```
Example 4:
Input: {2,1, 10, 40, 5, 6} , x=1000, y=3
Output: {{2},{1},{5}} or {{2,1},{5}}
```

I have searched though the internet, but I couldn't find a similar problem. So, I made my own algorithm. Unfortunately the time complexity is exponential. I'm not going to give my solution, because I have created a tunnel vision and want to start from scratch with fresh ideas.

So, here is my question: Do you know an algorithm to solve this problem as efficient as possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*P.S. As a reminder, don't underestimate the complexity of the problem.*

Comment: You should define x and y. It's not clear what they are

Comment: Check out the "Knapsack problem"

Comment: What is `x`? The upper bound of the number of subarrays?

Comment: The knapsack problem is weakly NP complete, but trying to reduce it to this seems to require making the length the cost, so doesn't work. It does kind'a imply you should try a similar dynamic programming approach to the one they use.

Comment: Please don't tag spam.

Comment: If the total number of element is `y`, so this prob is equivalent to find the sub-array with y element with minimum sum right? Not really sure what is the meaning of `x` here?

Comment: As others have said, your definition of `x` doesn't match the last example.  You say it's the number of subarrays, but in the last example it's not.  You can't expect a useful answer to an ill-defined problem.

Comment: Is x the max number of subarrays to find?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my try to apply the DP approach.

Let `M(I, Y, X, L)` be the the minimum total sum of subarrays where:

- `I` - we use the first `I` elements of the original array `ARR`
- `Y` - the count of all elements in the subarrays
- `X` - upper bound for number of subarrays
- `L = 1` if the last (`I`-th) element is included in one of the subarrays forming the minimum value, otherwise `L = 0`

Then the following formulas apply:

`M(I, Y, X, 1) = ARR[I] + MIN(M(I-1, Y-1, X, 1), M(I-1, Y-1, X-1, 0))`

and

`M(I, Y, X, 0) =  MIN(M(I-1, Y, X, 1), M(I-1, Y, X, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

**[NEW SOLUTION USING DYNAMIC PROGRAMMING]**

I've spent a lot of time on this, hope it works well. I commented it to make it clear as always. Hope this helps, i didn't manage to find anything more efficent, sorry.

```
package temp2;

public class Main {
    private static int
            X=1, //This i understood is the max number of subarray. Change it to find counterexample.
            Y=2, //This is the number of elements you want as result. Change it to find counterexample.
            VERY_LARGE_NUMBER=1000000;

    private static int array[] = {1, 100, 2, 2, 100, 1}; //just your array. Change it to find counterexample. Remember to leave the bounds (9999) as i explained in the answer.



    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Obtained result: "+alg(array.length-1, 0, 0, 0, false));
    }

    public static int alg(int index, int partialSum, int numberOfUsedArrays, int numberOfUsedElements, boolean beforeIsInResults){

        /**
         * If the remaning number to analize are equal than the max number of elements minus the number of elements found AND
         * i can add them to the results adding a new subarray OR using the adjacent one, i add all the value to the result sum.
         */
        if(index+1+numberOfUsedElements == Y && (numberOfUsedArrays<X || (beforeIsInResults && numberOfUsedArrays<=X))){
            int summ = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<=index; i++)
                summ+=array[i];
            return summ+partialSum;
        }

        /**
         * If i don't have any subarray to create or to use (if is possible to connect to the adjacent) AND i don't enough elements
         * in the computed solution i don't consider this solution.
         */
        if((((numberOfUsedArrays > X && beforeIsInResults) || (numberOfUsedArrays >= X && !beforeIsInResults)) && numberOfUsedElements < Y )){   //Old condition i think is no more needed: || (index+1+numberOfUsedElements == Y && ((numberOfUsedArrays > X && beforeIsInResults) || (numberOfUsedArrays >= X && !beforeIsInResults)))){
            return VERY_LARGE_NUMBER;
        }

        /**
         * If the index is out of bound OR i don't have any more subarrays left OR i reach the max number of element of the result i return the computed solution.
         */
        if( index < 0 || ((numberOfUsedArrays > X && beforeIsInResults) || (numberOfUsedArrays >= X && !beforeIsInResults)) || numberOfUsedElements >= Y )
            return partialSum;


        /**
         * I check if the best solution contains OR not contain the selected index. The only difference from if to else is that in case in which i choose to
         * add the element to the result is the element computed before (index+1) was selected no new array has been used else i need to update the number of array used.  
         */
        if(beforeIsInResults)
            return Math.min(
                    alg(index-1, partialSum+array[index], numberOfUsedArrays, numberOfUsedElements+1, true),
                    alg(index-1, partialSum, numberOfUsedArrays, numberOfUsedElements, false));
        else
            return Math.min(
                    alg(index-1, partialSum+array[index], numberOfUsedArrays+1, numberOfUsedElements+1, true),
                    alg(index-1, partialSum, numberOfUsedArrays, numberOfUsedElements, false));
    }
}
```

**[OLD NON WORKING SOLUTION]:** counter example: {1, 100, 2, 2, 100, 1} x = 1, y = 2

i found this alg. Unless i'm mistaken, complexity should be O(Y × array lenght).

n.b. all this assuming that your `X` variable means "max number of subarray"

```
Start: Find min in array not in result
       add it to result
       did we reach the max number of result?
       (Yes: end and print results) (No: go to Continue)

Continue: Compute min subarrays in the results.
          Is it equals to the max subarray (`Y`)?
          (No: go to Start) (Yes:Continue2)

Continue2: Find minimum value near one subarray.
           go to Continue.
```

I know this is a bit confusing, and this is not even the worst part.
I made the following code to test my alg. This is probably the worst code i've ever wrote.

I tried to keep it simple avoiding any "case special control" for example in some if there should be control to avoid any index out of bound exception (instead of this, since i'm lazy, i just placed some big useless values).

I've tried with all your combination and it worked. I didn't manage to find any counterexample.

If you need any more clarification just ask (i'll respond tommorow since in Italy here it's night ;) )

Here is the code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int     X=1000, //This i understood is the max number of subarray. Change it to find counterexample.
                Y=3, //This is the number of elements you want as result. Change it to find counterexample.
                temp, //This is just a value i used to store the minimum during the search along the array.
                tempIndex, //This is the one that keeps the index of temp.
                subarray=0, //This value will contain the minimum number of subarrays formed by the results. Since at the start there are no results, there are no subarray either. (to compare with X)
                resultsSize=0; //This will used to store the number of results temporary found (to compare with Y)

        int array[] = {9999,2,1,10,40,5,6,9999}; //just your array. Change it to find counterexample. Remember to leave the bounds (9999) as i explained in the answer.

        /*If my professor saw me use two parallel arrays instead of an array of objects 
         *I think he might kill me, but as I said, I'm lazy and this code just serves to make an example
         */
        boolean used[] = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}; //Just used to chceck if one value is already used in results.

        while(true){
            try{

                //The following code just find the minimum element not used.
                temp=9998;
                tempIndex=-1;
                for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                    if(array[i]<temp && !used[i]){
                        temp=array[i];
                        tempIndex=i;
                    }
                }

                //The following code add the found number to the results (just print it)
                used[tempIndex] = true;
                resultsSize++;
                System.out.print(temp+" ");

                //This is one of the two way to return with success. Basically we return when we found Y results.
                if(resultsSize == Y ) {
                    System.out.println("\nDone.");
                    return;
                }

                /*When i add an element to the result 3 things may happen.
                 *The result isn't near to any result, so it would create a new subarray
                 *The result is near to just one result, no new subarray created
                 *The result is just in the middle of two other result, adding it will result in fusion on two subarrays into one.
                 *The following code just use this rule to compute the subarray number
                 */
                if(used[tempIndex-1] && used[tempIndex+1]){ //third case
                    subarray--;
                }else if(!used[tempIndex-1] && !used[tempIndex+1]){ //first case
                    subarray++;
                }

                /*The following code will be executed only IF we reach the limit of subarrays. If so, he just try to add the smallest element without
                 *any subarray increment. If the subarrays get decremented (third case of the comment above) the while ends and the control returns back to the
                 *up side of this function early discussed.
                 */
                while(subarray == X){

                    //The following code just find the minimum element not used.
                    temp=9998;
                    tempIndex=-1;
                    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                        if(array[i]<temp && !used[i] && (used[i-1] || used[i+1])){
                            temp=array[i];
                            tempIndex=i;
                        }
                    }

                    //If this is true there are no minimum element near results which practically means that your 'Y' value is bigger than the length of the array
                    if(temp==9998){
                        System.out.println("\nYou shloud not ever come here.\ncheck if your 'Y' value is bigger than the length of the array");
                        return;
                    }

                    //The following code add the found number to the results (just print it)
                    used[tempIndex] = true;
                    resultsSize++;
                    System.out.print(temp+" ");

                    //This is one of the two way to return with success. Basically we return when we found Y results.
                    if(resultsSize == Y ){
                        System.out.println("\nDone.");
                        return;
                    }

                    //The following code checks with the new added result the number of subarrays get decremented.
                    //Remember that if subarrays get decremented the alg go back to the first part and search for minimum even non near to an existing subarray.
                    if(used[tempIndex-1] && used[tempIndex+1]){
                        subarray--;
                    }
                }
            } catch(Throwable e){ //Used for debugging, no more needed.

                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this has been useful or just a waste of time ;)

Comment: Sorry, but that is obviously wrong greedy algorithm.  Counterexample {1, 100, 2, 2, 100, 1}, x = 1, y = 2.

Comment: You're right, I'll try to work around that

Comment: I doubt that greedy algorithm could solve this problem

Comment: Yes, i'm starting to doubt it too XD actually i'm trying to find something with different approaches